# Script for verifying RDP log on functionality on linux

Tags: windows, linux, perl, bash, remote-desktop

At the moment we're having a few issues with terminal servers being up and running but unable to log on. (This is caused by a third-party application and it's being troubleshooted as we speak)

These issues forces us in to testing the RDP functionality manually way more often then we'd like to, hence why I'd like a script to do it for me.

So, a script that can return true or false with predefined credentials would be a blessing, anyone got any ideas? I could probably build an application myself if someone were to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Perl is the right direction, I would think, but you probably need to describe what you want to see happen.  What happens first?  What output are you looking for?  Etc.  Here is where you show us what code you've gotten started with, and ask questions where you're hung up.

Comment: Hi, what I'm looking for is merely a way to see if a user can log in or not, a sort of true or false sort of way. I haven't written anything yet since I'm not sure where to start. But since there are opensource applications out there (rdesktop) that can connect to RDP a script should be doable in some way.

Comment: What typically prevents a user from being able to log in?  Network outages?  Forgotten passwords?  Automating a Windows RDP session may be tricky, but if you could test for response from port 3389 on a given IP, for example, maybe that would suffice.  You could even have a Perl script send commands through the CLI of rdesktop, and use a cron job to automate it every so often.

Comment: This is what I received from the official rdesktop-users mailinglist, but I still haven't had a reply for running it without an X server. http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=WC20110630144354.200073%40mute.nu&forum_name=rdesktop-users